# Calling An ArcGIS Webmap's Scales

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I am composing an Arcpy tool to help users cache their current mxd's webmaps (our own services). I want to know a way to call the ArcGIS Web Map's scales with ArcPy. Once I have the web maps scales, I can apply policies and pass the desired scales to arcpy.gp.ExportMapServerCache for extraction.

Notably, the geoprocessing tool "Export Map Server Cache" calls the maps scales into the tools dialogue, a user then ticks the scales they want the cache. I figure if the tool can do it then some code can do it too...

My end goal is a tool that gets a web maps scales, applies an appropriate extraction extent polygon for the scale range, and extracts appropriate scales into a cache.

```
##### For Many Web Cache
arcpy.CreateFolder_management(UserProjectPathCache,lyr.name)
arcpy.AddMessage("    New Cache Folder:  "+ UserProjectPathCache +"\\"+lyr.name)
ServiceCache = (UserProjectPathCache +"\\"+lyr.name)

##### Passing To Publisher Connection String:
ExportService = UserProjectPath +"\\Temp_Pub_Connection\\"+lyr.name+".MapServer"
arcpy.AddMessage("    Temp Publisher Con: "+ExportService)

#TAKEN FROM THE GLOBAL IMAGERY SERVICE
S1 = 591657527.591555
S2 = 295828763.795777 
S3 = 147914381.897889
S4 = 73957190.948944
S5 = 36978595.474472
S6 = 18489297.737236
S7 = 9244648.868618
S8 = 4622324.434309
S9 = 2311162.217155
S10 = 1155581.108577
S11 = 577790.554289
S12 = 288895.277144
S13 = 144447.638572
S14 = 72223.819286
S15 = 36111.909643
S16 = 18055.954822
S17 = 9027.977411
S18 = 4513.988705
S19 = 2256.994353
S20 = 1128.497176

DefaultScales = "{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9};{10};{11};{12};{13};{14};{15};{16};{17};{18};{19}".format(S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10,S11,S12,S13,S14,S15,S16,S17,S18,S19,S20)

target_cache_path = ServiceCache
export_cache_type = "TILE_PACKAGE"  #"CACHE_DATASET" # "TILE_PACKAGE"
copy_data_from_server = "COPY_DATA" # Because the server might not have write access
storage_format_type ="COMPACT" # Easier To Move
num_of_caching_service_instances = 1 # I pulled this number from the air
area_of_interest = CacheAOI
export_extent = ""
overwrite ="MERGE"

arcpy.AddMessage("    --------------")
arcpy.AddMessage("        I: CACHING WEB MAP TO: "+ServiceCache)

################## EXPORT MAP CACHE HERE
try:
        arcpy.AddMessage("        I: CACHING WEB MAP: PLEASE WAIT...")
        arcpy.gp.ExportMapServerCache(ExportService, target_cache_path, export_cache_type, copy_data_from_server, storage_format_type, DefaultScales, num_of_caching_service_instances, CacheAOI, export_extent, "MERGE")
        arcpy.AddMessage("        I: CACHING WEB MAP: Completed")
        del ExportService
except Exception as e:
        arcpy.AddError("       "+e.message)
```

Comment: you can get the scale information from `status.gdb` situated at your server `C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgiscache\<service-name>`

Comment: My users will not have access to the Servers C.. But it's a good thought.

Comment: If you have scales with you like shown S1,S2... You can also check Export Tile Cache (Data Management) : http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000187000000 This tool doesn't need to have an access in C drive of Server.

Answer (score 1):

Bill from Esri Inc gave me a hand with this one. You can call the LOD via json:

```
    import urllib, json
    parameters = urllib.urlencode({'f':'json'})
    request = "http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer?" + parameters
    response = json.loads(urllib.urlopen(request).read())

    try:
        tileinfo = response['tileInfo']
        cachescales = []
        for lod in tileinfo['lods']:
            cachescales.append(lod['scale'])

        print cachescales
    except:
        print "tileInfo key does not exist in JSON response; probably not a cached map service."
```